# Why is my DrawerToggle onClick not getting called?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, drawertoggle, actionbardrawertoggle

When I am adding a fragment to my activity I am changing the hamburger icon to back arrow image and trying to set onClick to it.
But for some reason it is not getting called!

```
((MyActivity)getActivity()).getmDrawerToggle().setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
((MyActivity)getActivity()).getmDrawerToggle().setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Hello Here",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: maybe you have some element on top of that button? check it. Or your app crash, its reports an errors? post details....

Comment: @Aspicas No my app doesn't crash. Also I don't have anything on top of that button.

Comment: post details... XML, Java Code... Debug your app...